# How to use assert in loop using pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I want to make a simple script to verify that all tables in GCP dataset have some data.
A dataset can contain multiple tables.

1) How to call assert for each table correctly?

2) I have to create separate test function for each dataset. Is that correct?

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pytest
CLIENT = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('key.json')


def count_verification(dataset):
    query = '''SELECT project_id, dataset_id, table_id, row_count
               FROM `''' + dataset + '.__TABLES__`;'
    query_job = CLIENT.query(query)
    return query_job


def test_count_verification(dataset):
    for row in count_verification(dataset):
        assert row['row_count'] != 0


def test_count_verification_1(dataset_1):
    for row in count_verification(dataset_1):
        assert row['row_count'] != 0


@pytest.fixture
def dataset():
    return 'bigquery-public-data:austin_311'


@pytest.fixture
def dataset_1():
    return 'amplified-way-272012:test_dataset'
```

Comment: Are you testing your code, or the data? If former, then use `assert` and `py.test`. If latter, then do not use these tools.

Comment: @rpoleski I'm testing data. Which tool will be more appropriate for this task?

Comment: Asking for a tool reference is off-topic here.  *I* would do this with a short `bash` or `python` script; your mileage may vary.

Comment: Ok, then don't use `assert`. Instead use normal `if` statement + `raise ValueError()` or similar. The `assert` statements can be turned off by the user. And you don't need `py.test` - just include the tests in your code that is executed.

Comment: For your second question have a look at https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/parametrize.html The idea is that you write your tests and make the input dynamic. In that way you also adhere to the DRY principle.